# StartafterDocument in firebase is not working as expected

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i wrote two firebase requests in a function that is intended to retrieve the comments of a user with a specific username(signed in user). Having gotten the the comments of the signed in user, those comments must not be loaded/read again from firebase when th function is called again. It is realized that the snapshot variable is always null/empty when the function is called 2nd, 3rd, 4th time etc. How  can I accurately get the other comments not being the same as the first set of comments stored in the querysnapshot variable?

for the snapshot variable, i tried this:

```
final snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('comments')
          .where('postId', isEqualTo: widget.document['postId'])
         ``your text`` .where('username', isNotEqualTo: widget.username)
         .where('datePublished', isNotEqualTo: null)
          //.orderBy('datePublished', descending: true)
          .startAfterDocument(_lastDocument)
          .limit(_increment)
          .get(); I also tried this: final snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('comments')
          .where('postId', isEqualTo: widget.document['postId'])
          //.where('username', isNotEqualTo: widget.username)
         // .where('datePublished', isNotEqualTo: null)
          //.orderBy('datePublished', descending: true)
          .startAfterDocument(_lastDocument)
          .limit(_increment)
          .get();
```

Here is the full code:

```
void _getComments() async {
    `print('called function');
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot;

    if (_lastDocument == null) {
      querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('comments')
          .where('postId', isEqualTo: widget.document['postId'])
          .where('username', isEqualTo: widget.username)
          .orderBy('datePublished', descending: true)
          .get();

      if (querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        _lastDocument = querySnapshot.docs.last;
        _comments.addAll(querySnapshot.docs);
      }
    } else {
      final snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('comments')
          .where('postId', isEqualTo: widget.document['postId'])
          //.where('username', isNotEqualTo: widget.username)
         // .where('datePublished', isNotEqualTo: null)
          //.orderBy('datePublished', descending: true)
          .startAfterDocument(_lastDocument)
          .limit(_increment)
          .get();


      if (snapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
       // _lastDocument = snapshot.docs.last;
        _lastDocumentOther = snapshot.docs.last;
        _comments.addAll(snapshot.docs);
      }
    }

    if (_comments.length >= _perPage) {
      setState(() {
        _hasMore = true;
      });
    }

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }`
```

Comment: The code a the top is kinda jumbled together - please use the code formatting tools {} when posting questions to make it easier to read. Also, including troubleshooting is important; does `widget.username`, `_lastDocument` etc resolve to what you expect? Please clean up the code and include troubleshooting details

Comment: yes, what you mentioned gave everything as expected. I am wondering whether it is the fact that I am using 2 queries that are somewhat unrelated as to why I get the result I get.

Comment: I am not sure I follow - there are multiple queries in the question so we don't know which ones are being used or what line of code is not producing the expected results. Can you clarify the question?